# Embeddable software that allows users to send game requests

Tags: gaming, embeddable

I'm working on a website where gamers can connect with each other. Let's say one gamer wants to play a match in Halo against another gamer, but none of his friends are available. I want him to be able to hop on to my website, request the game Halo, and see if anybody else wants to play. I've tried just a text chat, but that seems too simple, and anyway, people were just messing about. Is there any software that allows gamers- on my website- to choose a game, either from a dropdown list or by typing a word or two- and see if other gamers have requested the same thing.

Oh, and it has to be embeddable.

UPDATE: Just forgot to mention: Halo is just an example. It should work for either a game from a dropdown list (which should be quite large) or allow the user to input a game themselves.

Comment: This system will not be linked with the game itself, if I understand correctly, right? Mary says she wants to play Halo, Jorge says he wants to play Halo, your system makes the match and give Mary and Jorge the right info to go and connect on Halo manually, correct?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul yes, exactly

Comment: @NicolasRaoul any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean ny "embeddable"?

Comment: @Mawg It's basically a code that you can put on a web page so it's like an app on a website. All online games use embed codes.